# how to set up mongoengine with django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm starting to use mongoengine and i'm already stuck in the getting starting [link](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)
I'm running ubuntu 14.04.
Here's what I've done: 
    $ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 myproject
    source myproject/bin/activate
I then start the tutorial by running sudo pip install mongoengine(without sudo I had an error)

Then I have to right :

```
from mongoengine import *

connect('tumblelog')
```

But where do I have to write this? Do I have to install Django and write it in the settings?
I had already install mongodb but will it works with the virtualenv?

Comment: Configuring MongoEngine with Django can sometimes get quite confusing. I found an easier way to [connect Django with MongoDB](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/integrating-django-with-mongodb/).

Answer (score 0):

You say you get an error when you try to install `mongoengine`, but you do not say what it was. The purpose of virtual environments is to obviate the need to access system files, so you need to look at that before going too much further.

MongoDB is quite happy to work in virtual environments. You will write the `import` statement at the head of any module you write that needs to use MongooDB.

Comment: NO I installed it with sudo pip install mongoengine. But where do I writte code? Do i have to install django? because my project is empty

Comment: so I have to pip install django and replace the database by the connect function ? I already make a couple project with django but never using mongodb

Comment: You can't just replace a relational database with MongoDB and expect everything to work. I don't see why you expect the Mongo tutorial to give instructions for working with Django.